# Using Resteasy, how can I save an uploaded file without any character encoding conversion?

Tags: file-upload, character-encoding, resteasy

I'm trying to upload an XML file via a form using Resteasy on the server.  When I receive the file, I'm just saving it to disk.  The file is UTF-8-encoded, but it is being saved with the non-ASCII characters converted to question marks.  [This stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768656/how-to-get-text-xml-as-utf-8-from-a-multipart-form-data-request-with-resteasy) led me to believe that this line is the problem:

```
//convert the uploaded file to input stream
InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
```

I tried using a pre-process interceptor to set the encoding to UTF-8, but that didn't work.  Besides, setting the encoding on the server is the wrong solution -- I really want to be able to handle files with any encoding, and just save them to disk without doing any conversion.  Is there any way I can do this using Resteasy?

Here's all of the code I'm using to handle the upload:

ResourcesHandler.java:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public void createOrReplaceResource(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");
    ResourceManager.createResource(null, inputParts);
}
```

ResourceManager.java:

```
public static void createResource(String packName, List<InputPart> inputParts) throws IOException {
    String dirname = DYNAMIC_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY;
    if (packName != null && !packName.isEmpty()) {
        dirname = dirname + "/" + packName;
    }

    //This code taken from: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/
    String fileName = "";
    for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
        fileName = getFileName(header);

        //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
        InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        //construct upload file path
        fileName = dirname + "/" + fileName;

        writeFile(bytes, fileName);
    }
}

//This code taken from: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/
//get uploaded filename, is there a easy way in RESTEasy?
private static String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> header) {

    String[] contentDisposition = header.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");

    for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
        if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

            String[] name = filename.split("=");

            String finalFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
            return finalFileName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//This method taken from: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/
//Save to a file.
private static void writeFile(byte[] content, String filename) throws IOException {

    File file = new File(filename);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

    fop.write(content);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

}
```

That's Apache commons-io IOUtils which is converting the InputStream to a byte array.

Comment: InputStream handles bytes, so it should work. Please post more code, preferably from the very moment you receive response to the moment you save the file.

Comment: ok, I've posted the rest of the relevant code.